# Change the values of different rows in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How I can change value of different selected rows? I want to select rows and change value and for other unselected rows i don't want to change values.

This is an example of the selected rows. I or my users can choose other strings to change, me need a universal code. Pls help.

My tableView looks like this:

[image]

My code not work, but looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var weekdayTime: [String] = ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00"]

var weekdayPrice: [Int] = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return weekdayTime.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "weekdayCell", for: indexPath) as! WeekdayPriceCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = weekdayTime[indexPath.row]

    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(weekdayPrice[indexPath.row])"

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if (arrayOfSelectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath)) {

        cell?.accessoryType = .none

    } else {

        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    }
}

@IBAction func changePrice(_ sender: Any) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Set price on selected time, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in

        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad

        textField.placeholder = "Set price"

    }

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancal", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Change", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

        if let price = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
            // it's not work code, i think on this need to create new code
            self.weekdayPrice = [Int(price)!]

            print(self.weekdayPrice)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

I think my problem here `self.weekdayPrice = [Int(price)!]` and below, but i don't know where to look to resolve my issue.

Comment: In what way doesn't your code work? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't understand how to change my selected rows. In example it's rows 0, 3, 6 with value 1000, 4000, 7000. How i can change in rows 0, 3, 6 value on 1000 (for example)?

Comment: 1. You need to put the indexPath( or row value if you only have one section) of your selected row in an array(for example, [0, 3, 6]). 2. Then when you changed the value in the alertController, you should update the `weekdayPrice` array according to the indexPath's row(change `weekdayPrice[0] = newValue, weekdayPrice[3] = newValue ...`). 3. In the end, you reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

1. add the following line after `weekdayPrice`
   `var weekdaySelectedFlags = Array(repeating: false, count: 7)`
2. add the following line after `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method

   ```
   weekdaySelectedFlags[indexPath.row] = !weekdaySelectedFlags[indexPath.row]
   ```
3. replace the following lines of `self.weekdayPrice = [Int(price)!]`

   ```
           if let priceValue = Int(price) {
               self.weekdaySelectedFlags.enumerated().forEach() {
                   if $1 == true {
                       self.weekdayPrice[$0] = priceValue
                   }
               }
           } else {
               print("Failed to convert the input text to Int value")
           }
   ```

   or

   ```
           if let priceValue = Int(price) {
               for (key ,flag) in self.weekdaySelectedFlags.enumerated() {
                   if flag == true {
                       self.weekdayPrice[key] = priceValue
                   }
               }
           } else {
               print("Failed to convert the input text to Int value")
           }
   ```

   Then your "change" action would look like this

   ```
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Change", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

           if let price = alertController.textFields?.first?.text {
               // it's not work code, i think on this need to create new code
               if let priceValue = Int(price) {
                   self.weekdaySelectedFlags.enumerated().forEach() {
                       if $1 == true {
                           self.weekdayPrice[$0] = priceValue
                       }
                   }
               } else {
                   print("Failed to convert the input text to Int value")
               }


               print(self.weekdayPrice)
               self.tableView.reloadData()

           }
       }))
   ```